# Play button over thumbnail with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to display play button over a thumbnail with CSS in my WordPress. I tried many methods but always is bad. Can you help me, where I am wrong?

```css
.post-thumbnail-sidebar {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.post-thumbnail-sidebar embed,
.post-thumbnail-sidebar iframe,
.post-thumbnail-sidebar object {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.post-thumbnail-sidebar a {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   background: url("https://i.imgur.com/FPwyRnP.png") no-repeat;
   height: 85px;
   width: 136px;
   top: 100%;
   left: 100%;
   margin: -64px 0 0 -88px;
}
```

```html
<a class="post-thumbnail-sidebar" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( $r_post_thumb_size, array( 'itemprop' => 'image' ) ); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Not enough information to help: try to recreate the problematic part e.g. in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Not enough but i think you can start with this.
[here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40w57geL/7/)

```css
.second-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px 
}
```

```html
<div>
<img class="background-img" width="100%" height="100%" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" src=  "https://vincentloy.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/in-time-2011-r5-line-xvid-fusion_screenshot_4.jpg">
<a href = "https://vincentloy.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/in-time-2011-r5-line-xvid-fusion_screenshot_4.jpg"><img class="second-img" width="100%" height="100%" src = "http://sanyangfrp.com/data/out/805/511806414-play-button-png.png" /> </a>
</div>
```